# MySQL has gone away with two connections

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm using MySQL 5.6.19 on OSX 10.9.5 (DMG installation from mysql.com) and I'm receiving the infamous MySQL has gone away when I try to open two connections to this server.

If I try connecting from PHP:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

In `mysql` on Terminal, it won't connect either, but shows another error:

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'sending authentication information', system error: 32
```

I already changed a bunch of parameters in my.cnf, here is how it's now:

```
[mysqld]
join_buffer_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 
connect_timeout = 300
wait_timeout = 300
net_read_timeout = 300
net_write_timeout = 300
max_allowed_packet = 128M
max_connections = 50
table_open_cache = 1024
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
```

None of those parameters helped. `max_allowed_packet` is a famous solution, but even that isn't helping. This is really weird because I'm not even using the database, no queries running, nothing, I just open the first connection, and with the second I'm receiving the error.

Any idea?

**EDIT 1**

Restarting MySQL solves this for two or three days, then it happens again.

Comment: I'm not sure it's related, but I think you have set `join_buffer_size` value way too high.

Comment: @MannyCalavera I know, but I tried it from 2MB to 128MB, and none helped. I'll lower it to 2MB again.

Comment: Can you list the error log message? There's good chance the mysql crashed for some reason.

Comment: @MannyCalavera MySQL isn't crashing, the connection that is open runs query without any problem, but I can't open a second connection. My `hostname.err` has no errors listed, just MySQL's startup info.

Comment: `SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS = 2;` and try again?  Then check the MySQL error log...